# Compare a timestamp in WHERE clause of Access/SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-timestamp

I'm working in an Access front end linked to an SQL Server back end.

In one of our tables, the data type on the SQL Server is timestamp.  I want to write a WHERE statement that limits the data returned to records created in the last 30 seconds.  I tried the following

```
WHERE myTime > DATEADD(s, -30, SYSDATETIME())
```

But get the following error:

```
Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with timestamp
```

I've been researching casting and converting, but exactly where or how I would do that isn't clear.  Any insight?  And is using SYSDATETIME() the right thing to do?

Comment: [Aaron Bertrand - Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `datetime` type for your `myTime` column.   I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the [`timestamp` datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

From the referenced article:

> The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime
>   data type.

Comment: Ok, well you're not going to be able to use a `timestamp`-type column to get the last 30 seconds (or any timeframe) worth of data.   If there is no `datetime` column in the table, then I'm afraid you just can't do what you want.

Comment: Got it.  That's all I got, so I suppose it is what it is.